# MySQL 5.7 remove duplicate rows in the same table based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table with already existing records, I want to add a Unique constraint on multiple columns(app_instance_config_uuid, external_resource_id and spaceId), but first, I need to remove already existing duplicates.
This is an example of the table I want to add the constraint.

[image]

The best solution i found is

```
DELETE FROM spaces_apps 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM ( SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM spaces_apps 
GROUP BY spaceId, app_instance_config_uuid, external_resource_id 
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1 ) temp )
```

but the issue is that it only deletes one duplicate and if I need to delete more then one i need to run it again.

Important note that this is MySQL5.7 so using ROW_COUNT() and similar approaches doesn't work.

UPDATE:
The first solution works even better when just changing IN to NOT IN and removing the HAVING clause! Thanks to @Pankaj for pointing this!

```
DELETE FROM spaces_apps 
    WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM ( SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM spaces_apps 
    GROUP BY spaceId, app_instance_config_uuid, external_resource_id )temp )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this. It's not the prettiest but it's the only one that works in my case.

```
DELETE t1 FROM table_name t1
INNER JOIN table_name t2 
WHERE 
    t1.created_at < t2.created_at AND
    t1.app_instance_config_uuid=t2.app_instance_config_uuid  AND
    t1.external_resource_id=t2.external_resource_id AND
    t1.spaceId=t2.spaceId;
```

Comment: In the original solution you found, replace ```IN``` with ```NOT IN```, that should just leave one and delete rest.

Comment: It removes all the rows and leavs only one. It removes those that are not duplicate also @Pankaj

Comment: Need to remove ```HAVING``` clause.

Comment: You are right. That's actually a better way. Thanks a lot @Pankaj